# Запятая перед "и"

Tags: пунктуация

Не пойму, сложноподчиненное или сложносочиненное это предложение (и нужна ли запятая  перед И): "И это при том, что я был обычный советский мальчишка(,) и до этого мне всегда снились светлые, очень добрые и радостные сны".

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Сложноподчиненное предложение с однородными придаточными, поэтому запятая перед И не нужна.
О том, что это сложноподчиненное предложение, говорит наличие подчинительного союза *притом что*. Кстати, данные о правописании этого союза расходятся. Вот, ответ с "Грамоты":последнее издание «Русского орфографического словаря» указывает как правильное написание *притом что*, хотя в остальных словарях, справочниках и художественных текстах пишется: *при том что*.

Во всех своих ответах "Грамота" дает как верное слитное написание.